# Check if time is between two times and interval

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, intervals

Let's say there are two given times and an interval. I can check if the time is between two given times like so:

```
$timeA = '00:30:00';
$timeB = '14:00:00';
$interval = 30; // minutes

$inputTime = '00:45:00'; // user inputted time

$input = new DateTime($inputTime);
$begin = new DateTime($timeA);
$end = new DateTime($timeB);

if($input >= $begin && $input <= $end) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Fail';
}
```

But how can I check for the interval? For example, the interval is 30 minutes so only show success message if `$inputTime` is between `$begin` and `$end` AND one of the following:

```
00:30:00
01:00:00
01:30:00
02:00:00
02:30:00
03:00:00
03:30:00
04:00:00
04:30:00
...
13:30:00
14:00:00
```

and if it does not fall on one of the "interval" times, then it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the times in between the two given times and if it lands on an "interval" time, you can break from the `for` loop and echo out a success message.

For example:

```
$found = false;
for ($i=0; $i < 1440; $i++) {
    $begin->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $interval . 'M'));
    if($begin == $input) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    } elseif($begin > $input || $begin > $end) {
        $found = false;
        break;
    }
}

if($found) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
    echo 'Fail';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime()` to convert to integer time and then find the difference. Then compare the difference between that time and 30 minutes.

Comment: Please expand on it?